# How can I redirect a flash-based GET request?

Tags: flash, get, greasemonkey

I have a webpage that I want to mess with using Greasemonkey. There are flash headers at the top (With changing images).
I already have all those images and have reproduced the file structure so I can redirect the image requests.

This is how the flash object works:
It loads, and then whenever it goes to the next image in the slideshow it sends a GET request to retrieve the image. I want to redirect that request to my image so that the slideshow is now showing my images.

- The site is [the Haslett Public School's page](http://www.haslett.k12.mi.us/). I want to change the images to ponies.
- [The flash object](http://www.haslett.k12.mi.us/images/headers/header_theme_80.swf)

I don't want to edit the flash object, just redirect the requests.

Example: Redirect:

```
http://www.haslett.k12.mi.us/images/album/11139/hs/album_3964_1327077935.png
```

To:

```
http://anotherdomain.net/images/album/11139/hs/album_3964_1327077935.png
```

Or, most likely scenario, I'll use an image sharing site and I'll redirect to:

```
http://imagesite.com/image/album_3964_1327077935.png
```

The 11139 directory is sometimes different, so is the HS directory, but the file names won't actually change from old file to new file.

The file names are all different, so I think I can just redirect the specific album requests (11139, 11140, 11141, etc). to one directory.

Here's what I have: I got it from some example code, but a have a feeling that it just edits any  and  tags, or maybe  tags. Mine needs to actually redirect the GET requests.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Sudofox image redirect 
// @namespace      imagehost redirect
// @description    Replace requests for images with 
// @include        http://www.haslett.k12.mi.us/*
// @include        https://haslett.k12.mi.us/*
// @include        https://www.haslett.k12.mi.us/*
// @include        http://haslett.k12.mi.us/*
// ==/UserScript==

var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
  p = /\/images\/album\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/;
  res = p.exec(a[i]);

  if (res!=null) {
    a[i].href = 'http://site.com/image/' + res[1] + '.png';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Flash, not Javascript. You can't mess with that from the outside. Without access to the server to actually redirect the requests, your chances are slim to none.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that. I just discovered an xml file that makes things a *whole* lot easier. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Greasemonkey (and javascript) cannot access Flash-based requests.  So this is not possible with a Greasemonkey script.

Here are some alternatives:

- Find or make a Firefox add-on. [*Redirector*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/redirector/) is pretty good, but it may not work in this case. (But try it and make sure.)
- Install and run a proxy server.  [*Fiddler*](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is pretty good.
- Change your `hosts` configuration and set up a web-server, if necessary.  See ["How to redirect a URL to a local file?"](https://superuser.com/q/222810/41023).